# JS - add click event listener for all elements matching a querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

I have li elements to which I'm trying to add click events that match the querySelector : `.sidebar-nav li:not(.top)`. I have this code :

```
var sidebarItems = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-nav li:not(.top)");
// For each sidebar item, register a click function
for (var i = 0; i === sidebarItems.length; i++) {
  sidebarItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("fromage");
  })
};
```

However, no event listeners are added. The firefox dev tools show nothing, and nothing logs to the console when I click an element.
I checked in the JS console, sidebarItems has the correct node list.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop will loop for as long as the condition is true.

Your condition is `i === sidebarItems.length` so unless the length is `0`, it will **never** be true.

Loop while `i` is **less** then the length of the array-like object.

```
for (let i = 0; i < sidebarItems.length; i++) {
```